# How do we detect when Power Source from EB to DG

Tags: ups

Is there a way we can detect if power source switch from EB to DG?

Are there any circuits or alarms already there in market which triggers when the power source changes from Normal Power Supply to Backup Supply 
?

For Example, my UPs starts beeping as soon as it got disconnected from Main power source.
 It might be very basic question, but I am not very sure about low level details

Comment: who are EB and DG?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, EB is Electricity Board /Utility power Suppy and DG is from power source like a Generator or inverter Battery

Comment: Not sure if this what you are asking but my office UPS units have a USB interface and can (through software) ask the computer to shut down gracefully before the battery is exhausted.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I am looking for an alarm which will sound as soon as my power swtich from AC to DC.

Comment: So what does DG stand for precisely?

Comment: Most UPS units beep when their battery is draining.

Comment: When using unfamiliar acronyms or abbreviations (or even some reasonably familiar ones) you should define them in the question. If only using them once or twice it is better to write them out in full.

Answer (score 1):

The top set of contacts will be closed  when EB is active and open when it isn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In apartment buildings generator power comes on the same line as the municipal power. But generator backup power is significantly more expensive than municipal(electricity board) power. It's not always apparent, which is powering your flat. I think what he is asking is, is there a way to detect what source of electricity is currently in use, so he can curb his usage accordingly.

Fans and light do change behavior a little bit under generator power, I'd bet you would be able to see this difference on an oscilloscope, and if you could see a straight forward difference, you could have someone make a way to auto detect what power source you are on using a raspberrypi or arduino
.